# Chromecast-Volume progress bar visible on TV but not on my android mobile device

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am using following below code to increase and decrease volume of TV while playing video from device through Chromecast.I can see the volume increase decrease progress bar on tv while pressing volume up down buttons on device but i can't see the volume progress bar on my android mobile device.I want to see the progress bar on both tv and my mobile device as it is visible in most chromecast support apps.How can i do that?

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if(routeselected) {
        double volume = Cast.CastApi.getVolume(mApiClient);

        switch (event.getKeyCode()) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

                try {
                    Cast.CastApi.setVolume(mApiClient, volume + 0.02);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return true;


            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:

                try {
                    Cast.CastApi.setVolume(mApiClient, volume - 0.02);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return true;


        }
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a proper volume feedback ui on your phone (which should show a cast icon when you are casting even when your app is not in front), you need to use MediaRouter + either RemoteControlClient or MediaSession. For a MediaRouter path, you can look at the CastCompanionLibrary; MediaSession has a couple of bugs that once they are fixed, CCL will move to use that instead of the deprecated RemoteControlClient.